# How do we get admin current screen by post id instead of screen id?

Tags: wordpress

I need to add css on one single admin page which has post=183 .. Here id is 183.. The below code will work for all the pages but in my case I just want this to have effect in single page. So the best thing will have to be through page/post_id.

```
function this_screen() {
  $current_screen = get_current_screen();
  if(( $current_screen ->id === "page") ) {
      wp_enqueue_style(
      'gp_fp', 
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin/css/block.css');
  }
}
```

Appreciate help.

Comment: I guess you could access `global $post` and check it there - but it won't work if you are creating a new one - only if you are editing an existing

Answer (score 0):

I would check that:

- Current page is admin (so it won't affect the front-end)
- Current page is post ID = 183

  ```
  $post_id = 183;
  if (is_admin() && get_post_status($post_id) === false) {
    // do something
  }
  ```

Reference: https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-post-exists-by-id/